# Использование функций сторонней библиотеки из c++ dll

Tags: c, dll

Какой аналог кода (C#):

```
[DllImport("NTDirect.dll")]
public static extern int Last(string instrument, double price, int size);
```

для C++ библиотеки (dll).
Пробовал вот так:

```
typedef void(__stdcall *last_func)(char* instrument, double price, int size);

HMODULE nt_lib;
last_func Last;


//=== Стандартная точка входа для DLL ==========================================================================//
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    char err_msg[10];

    //Каждому событию соответствует свое значение аргумента fdwReason, передаваемого функции DllMain при его возникновении   
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: // Подключение DLL          
        nt_lib = LoadLibrary("NTDirect.dll");
        if (!nt_lib) {
            OutputDebugString("could not load the dynamic library");

            sprintf_s(err_msg, "%d", GetLastError());
            OutputDebugString(err_msg);

            return FALSE;
        }

        //# resolve function address here
        Last = (last_func)GetProcAddress(nt_lib, "Last");
        if (!Last) {
            OutputDebugString("could not locate the function");

            sprintf_s(err_msg, "%d", GetLastError());
            OutputDebugString(err_msg);

            return FALSE;
        }
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: // Отключение DLL
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:  // Создание нового потока
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:  // Завершение потока
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
    ...
    char* instr = "TEST";
    Last(instr, 200, 100);
```

Ошибок во время загрузки и получения функции нет. Получаю ошибку при вызове функции из dll:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

Может проблема в первом параметре?

Comment: В вашем коде отсутствует проверка как загрузки DLL, так и получения адреса процедуры. Сложно сказать что у вас за ошибка, какой ее код и где именно вы ее получили. Поэтому проверка LoadLibrary и GetProcAddress с обязательным вызовом GetLastError в случае ошибки - то, чего не хватает вашему коду.

Comment: Добавил проверку. Ошибок в строках загрузки библиотеки и функции нет. Ошибку получаю при вызове функции.

Comment: Так вы из одной DLL другую загружаете что ли? Почему не в DllMain?

Comment: Да. Это c++ библиотека, в которой я загружаю другую библиотеку и хочу использовать ее функции. Перенес загрузку в DllMain. Не помогло.

Comment: И библиотека загружена, и адрес получен? На чем библиотека писана, кстати?

Comment: Прохожусь по коду в отладчике, никаких ошибок нет ни при загрузке библиотеки, ни при загрузке функции. Как узнать получен ли адрес? На чем написана библиотека, к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - там написано как определять статус получения адреса. В общем, runtime пишет дело: возможно функция с другой конвенцией вызова и в этом проблема.

Comment: В C# описанный в теме код работает. Тогда вопрос актуальный, какой аналог кода C# необходимо применить в C++ Dll?

Comment: Попробовал вызвать функцию, которая возвращает int и в качестве параметра тоже принимает int. Результат тот-же.

Answer (score 1):

Реализация на самом деле рабочая. Проблема была в самой библиотеке NTDirect.dll. После переустановки программы (NinjaTrader) с которой она поставляется все заработало.